# ¿Cómo puedo conectarme a 2 bases de datos SQL en 2 servidores distintos pero con las mismas tablas Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Ya intente crear una carpeta donde hice un entity framework a cada base de datos y fue correcta la conexión, el problema rádica en que en ambas bases de datos existen las mismas tablas con los mismos campos.

El problema que obtengo es de ambiguedad al ocupar la misma tabla.

The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type 'bcUsuario'

Answer (score 0):

Desactiva la cache, Entity Framework por defecto guarda todos los datos en memoria para acelerar las consultas, la segunda vez, primero busca en la memoria y luego si hace Query en la base de datos.

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
.AsNoTracking()
.ToList();
```

Si desactivas la cache las transacciones van a ser mas lentas.

Otra opción si estas usando un inyector de dependencias también puedes hacer transacciones scope.

Comment: Como es que estas usando dos bases de datos con las mismas tablas, cual es su objetivo

Comment: Es para sincronizar información en ambas bases, las bases se encuentran en distintos servidores. @MiguelZarate.
Lo que requiero es hacer consulta de ciertas tablas y ver si tienen cambios, en caso de que si los tengas, debo de pasar la información a la otra base.

Comment: Para sincronizar base de datos es mejor usar las herramientas de SQL, que base de datos tienes y donde estan alojadas.

Comment: Igual lo pensé pero se tienen que hacer unos procesos por SDK, ambas están en SQL server. Debo de hacer consultas a la base 1 y hacer procesos por SDK hacía la base 2. Y van a estar comunicadas por una VPN, por tal motivo puedo tener acceso y puedo hacer la conexión a ambas.